# Binomial identity $\sum_{r=0}^n(2r+1)\binom{n}{r}^2=(n+1)\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Problem: prove that $\sum_{r=0}^n(2r+1)\binom{n}{r}^2=(n+1)\binom{2n}{n}$

My attempt:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^n(2r+1)\binom{n}{r}^2
&= 2\sum_{r=0}^nr\binom{n}{r}^2 + \sum_{r=0}^n\binom{n}{r}^2 \\
&= 2\sum_{r=1}^n\left[r\cdot \frac{n}{r} \binom{n-1}{r-1}\binom{n}{r}\right] + \binom{2n}{n} \\
&= 2n\sum_{r=1}^n\left[\binom{n-1}{r-1}\binom{n}{r}\right] + \binom{2n}{n} \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Need some more steps, have not arrived at desired right side. [is that what you meant by "my attempt"?]

Answer (score 2):

You're merely missing
$$
\sum_{r=1}^n\binom{n-1}{r-1}\binom{n}{r} = \sum_{r=1}^n\binom{n-1}{r-1}\binom{n}{n-r}=\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\frac12 \binom{2n}{n}.
$$